# How to split pyramid volume into slices for Riemann sum.

Tags: volume, riemann-sum

I'm working on a problem:
A pyramid of height  `H`  has a square base  `a` by  `a`. Find the area  `A`  at height `h`.  If the rock used to build the pyramid weighs approximately  `w`=100lb/ft3,  how much work did it take to lift all the rock?
[source](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/6-5-physical-applications#fs-id1167793496078)

My plan is:

- split the pyramid into infinitely thin layers, obtain formula for volume of each individual slice;
- multiply volume by density given to get weight of slice;
- multiply weight by earth gravity `g` to get force needed to lift slice;
- multiply force by distance the slice needs to be lifted to get work;
- use resulting work formula in a Riemann sum and convert it to a definite integral;

I need a check on volume formula. I took `x` axis starting at the top of the pyramid and pointing down.

Side of slice:
$$
a_i=a\cdot \frac{x_i}{H}=\frac{a}{H}x_i
$$

Area of slice:

$$
A_i=\left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2x^2_i
$$

Using pyramid frustum volume formula:

$$
V_{frustrum}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot h_{frustrum}\cdot \left(A_{top}+A_{bottom}+\sqrt{A_{top}\cdot A_{bottom}}\right)
$$

I get volume of a slice:

$$
V_i=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\cdot \left(\left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2x^2_{i-1}+\left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2x^2_i+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2x^2_{i-1}\cdot \left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2x^2_{i}}\right)
$$

$$
V_i=\frac{1}{3}\cdot Δx\cdot \left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2\left(x^2_{i-1}+x^2_i+x_{i-1}\cdot x_i\right)
$$

Now, my question, can I assume
$$
x_{i-1}=\:x_i
$$

and simplify the above to

$$
V_i=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \:Δx\cdot \:\left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2\cdot 3x^2_i=\:Δx\cdot \:\:\left(\frac{a}{H}\right)^2\cdot \:x^2_i
$$

?

And in general, when can I assume $x_{i-1}=\:x_i$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of doing a Riemann sum is that you use square blocks, not frustums! You know that the volume of a frustum lies between
$$\frac{a^2}{H^2}x_{i-1}^2(x_i-x_{i-1})\le V_i\le\frac{a^2}{H^2}x_i^2(x_i-x_{i-1})$$
And so the biggest error you can make by choosing either $x_i$ or $x_{i-1}$ is no more than
$$\begin{align}\Delta V_i&\le\frac{a^2}{H^2}(x_i^2-x_{i-1}^2)(x_i-x_{i-1})\\
&=\frac{a^2}{H^2}(x_i+x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1})^2\le2\frac{a^2}{H}(x_i-x_{i-1})\max(x_i-x_{i-1})\end{align}$$
So the biggest error you could make in volume is
$$\Delta V\le2\frac{a^2}{H}\max(x_i-x_{i-1})\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-x_{i-1})=2a^2\max(x_i-x_{i-1})$$
Thus you can make the error as small as you want by making the biggest step in $x$ small enough. Then if we let $x_i=\frac{iH}N$ so $x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac HN$ we get
$$\begin{align}V&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{a^2}{H^2}x_i^2(x_i-x_{i-1})=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{a^2Hi^2}{N^3}\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}
\frac{a^2HN(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N^3}=\frac{a^2H}{3}\end{align}$$
Just a hint of course because you seem to be on the right track otherwise.

Comment: Can you please explain the right part of $$ \frac{a^2}{H^2}\left(x_i+x_{i-1}\right)\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)^2\le 2\frac{a^2}{H}\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\max \left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right) $$ ?

Comment: Since $x_i\le H$ and $x_{i-1}\le H$ it follows that $x_1+x_{i-1}\le2H$. The definition of a Riemann sum uses the limit as the biggest step $x_i-x_{i-1}$ goes to zero. In $\epsilon,\delta$ terms we promise that $$\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx-\sum_{i=1}^Nf(x_i^*)(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|<\epsilon$$ whenever $a=x_0<x_1\dots<x_N=b$ and each $0<x_i-x_{i-1}<\delta$ and each $x_i^*\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$. Now it seems madness that I only said that one factor of $x_i-x_{i-1}<\delta$, but I am going to use the other factor of $x_i-x_{i-1}$ for telescoping sum. Thus $(x_1+x_{i-1})(x_1-x_{i-1})^2\le2H(x_1-x_{i-1})\delta$.